# Using Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects, during installation the installer freezes due to launch of the program before it finishes install

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Using the extension of Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects to make an installer for my application. It was working before I did an update. After the update the installer freezes due to it launches of the program before it finishes installing. It will stay frozen until I close the application and only after then it will continue with the installation. While it not a big deal would like to figure out why this happens.

Comment: You can use Dark from Wix toolset (https://documentation.help/WiX-v3.0/dark.htm) to decompile your msi to wix xml sources, then compare such a sources with problem and without it to figure out the differences. But this will not help to actually fix the problem, as you have no control over how the visual studio extension generates the installer.

Comment: "it launches of the program before it finishes installing", so you have to reveal more details on that. Don't open a new process and wait for it to finish, or you just observe the result of that.